# Исправьте код  в Паскале

Tags: pascal

Задача:подсчитать и напечатать количество положительных элементов, стоящих на четных местах С (8) = (-6.3; -1.0; 10.3; -8.8; 6.3; -1.1; 0.0; 0.1)
Вот мой код:

```
program laba7_3;
 const n=5;
 var m:array[1..n] of integer;
 k,i,j:integer;
 Begin
      writeln('Vvedit massiv');
      for i:=1 to n do
      read(m[i]);
          for i:=1 to n-1 do
          for j:=i+1 to n do
              if (m[j]>m[i]) then
                begin
                   k:=m[i];
                   m[i]:=m[j];
                   m[j]:=k;
              end;

      writeln('vidsort mas');
      for i:=1 to n do
      writeln(m[i],' ');
      readln(m[i]);
end.
```

Но вот ошибка:
 Ошибка времени выполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат. на строке read(m[i]);

Comment: оойой не то извиняюсь:
нужно посчитать массив в порядке убывания:  D(5)= (3,2;-6.3;-8.3;0.0;1.2),

Comment: но сам код подходит, просто не могу найти ошибку!

Comment: Осталось только угадать, как вы набрали саму входную строку...

И, кстати, почему у Вас массив Integer для действительных чисел?

Comment: @alexlz: так в этом и проблема, конечно. `3,2` не парсится в `Integer`. Оно, правда, и в `double` не распарсится, т. к. запятая.

Comment: учебные задачки не хотелось бы кому-то исправлять, разбирайтесь дальше, если будет конкретная проблема, то поможем.

Answer (score 1):

Тут в коде дважды встречается строки:

```
read(m[i])
```

и

```
readln(m[i]);
```

Автор вопроса не указал на какой из них выскакивает ошибка.

Если ошибка выскакивает все же в первом случае, то скорей всего он пытается вводить числа с плавающей точкой в массив integer. Согласно его комментариям следовало бы следать
массив типом real.

Если же во втором случае, то там после окончания цикла идет попытка ввести данные в массив m[i] c неопределенным для того случая индексом i. Тогда не удивительно, что там ошибка появляется. Следует заменить данную строку просто:

```
readln;
```

Так будет правильно. Программа будет ждать завершения программы по нажатию любой кнопки.

P.S. А вообще приведенный код вами, решает совершенно другую задачу, совсем не ту, что вы описали в задании!